# How to write routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to write

```
PUT    /users/:action/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update_admin", :controller=>"admin"}
```

in route.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading section 3.7 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
match '/users/:action/:id(.:format)' => 'admin#update_admin', :via => :put
```

Comment: I couldn't able to call the update_admin method on form submit. How to perfor this action?

Comment: Add `:as => :update_admin` and then you will have `update_admin_path` and `update_admin_url` helper methods.